# multiple markers resolving

Tags: android-emulator

I was testing the first app (see http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

at a point,I stuck..
it shows:

Multiple markers at this line
    - MyFirstActivity cannot be resolved to a variable
    - EXTRA_MESSAGE cannot be resolved or is 
     not a field

(see heading DISPLAY THE MESSAGE)

// I FOUND THE ABOVE GIVEN ERROR MESSAGE HERE

```
String message = intent.getStringExtra(MyFirstActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
```

HOW CAN I RESOLVE THIS?
THANK YOU

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't defined `MyFirstActivity` and `EXTRA_MESSAGE`.

Did you add `public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myapp.MESSAGE";` as it says in the tutorial? Check that `MyFirstActivity` is the name of your activity as well.